# Not detecting installed versions of Clang and GCC when compiling using Emscripten

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang, emscripten

Using windows and trying to compile emscripten:

```
emmake mingw32-make SUBTARGET=pacmantest SOURCES=C:\Users\Adam\Documents\GitHub\mame\drivers\pacman.cpp
```

I'm not used to compiling C but I have the latest versions installed of GCC and Clang but it's not using them for some reason. It's throwing the following error:

```
'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 

GCC 2.0.10 detected
clang version 6.0 or later needed.
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:1345: build/projects/sd1/mamepacmantest/gmake-asmjs/makefile] Error -1
```

Comment: Are all the executables in the toolchain reachable by the `PATH` variable? Can you start these from a terminal (cmd) window?

Comment: I can see a path for C:\MINGW\bin.

Comment: All the paths are correct.

Comment: Best add that information to your quesiton ([edit]). This will bump it up to the homepage and gain attention of other users here. Unfortunately I am not versed enough with emscripten to help you further. That was just one idea to check.

Comment: Taking a second look, it seems to require a specific clang version (I suspect emscripten is just used as frontend for clang). You might check again if clang is installed correctly and reachable in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your help it keeps referring to the wrong version despite having paths correct and latest version. Instead, i'm trying to install ubuntu and follow this guide https://www.knoats.com/books/self-hosted-applications/page/mame-web-application